# request syntactically incorrect: spring mvc

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

When I submit my jsp form mentioned below, it doesn't gets submitted and neither it shows anything in console.
Browser shows HTTP 404 status with error:The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

My JSP page is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add task</title>
<link href="<c:url value='/static/css/bootstrap.css' />" rel="stylesheet">
</link>
<link href="<c:url value='/static/css/app.css' />" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<c:set var="root" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
</head>

<body> 
<div class="generic-container">

    <div class="well lead">Add task</div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" action='<c:url value="addTask"/>'>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id"/>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" 
for="taskDescription">Task name</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input type="text" name="task" id="task" class="form-
control input-sm"/>
                    <div class="has-error">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" 
for="taskDescription">Task Description</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input type="text" name="taskDescription" 
id="taskDescription" class="form-control input-sm" />
                    <div class="has-error">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="fromTime">From 
Time</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input type="text" name="fromTime" id="fromTime" 
class="form-control input-sm" />
                    <div class="has-error">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="toTime">To 
Time</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input type="text" name="toTime" id="toTime" 
class="form-control input-sm" />
                    <div class="has-error">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-actions floatRight">
                        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-
primary btn-sm"/> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller action for handling the request is /addTask in AddTaskController

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.websystique.springmvc.model.AddTask;
import com.websystique.springmvc.service.TaskService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AddTaskController {

private TaskService taskService;

@RequestMapping("/task")
String task(){
    System.out.println("Inside task action");
    return "addTask/addTask";
}

@RequestMapping("/addTask")
String addTask(@ModelAttribute AddTask a){
    System.out.println("Inside addTask action");
    this.taskService.addTask(a);
    return "redirect:/task" ;
}

}
```

When I submit my add task form it shows the error:
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Comment: Try to remove the request mapping in the controller class and adf a / in c:url  _/addTask_

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes

```
<body> 
<div class="generic-container">

    <c:url var="addTask" value="/addTask"/>

    <div class="well lead">Add task</div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="${addTask}">
```